# CI/CD Gitlab ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown server host 'mysql' (-3)

Tags: mysql, docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

Lately I was implementing a gitlab CI/CD pipeline configuration for unit testing, in which I need to have a test database to run my tests on.

So I wrote this config as shown below running on a self hosted gitlab-runner server on a Digital ocean druplet.

But the pipeline failed with this error, `ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown server host 'mysql' (-3)`.

My CI/CD configuration:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

image: ahmed2zaky2/laravel-deploy-php81:latest

cache:
  key: "$CI_JOB_NAME-$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG"

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apk update && apk add zip
    - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
    - composer install --prefer-dist --no-ansi --no-interaction --no-progress --no-scripts
    - cp .env.testing.example .env.testing
    - cp .env.testing .env
    - php artisan key:generate
    - php artisan key:generate --env=testing
    - php artisan optimize
    - php artisan cache:clear
    - chmod 755 -R storage bootstrap/cache
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - vendor/
      - .env
      - .env.testing
  cache:
    paths:
      - vendor/
  only:
    - merge_requests
    - dev
    - main

test-unit:
  stage: test
  services:
    - name: mysql:8.0
      alias: mysql
      command: ["--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password"]
  before_script:
    - mysql --version
    - sleep 30
    - echo "SELECT 'OK';" | mysql -h$DB_HOST -u$MYSQL_USER -p$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD -e "CREATE DATABASE ${MYSQL_DATABASE};"
  script:
    - php artisan test
  variables:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_USER: root
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    MYSQL_DATABASE: jadwalh_test
    MYSQL_HOST: mysql
    DB_HOST: mysql
  dependencies:
    - build
  environment:
    name: development
  only:
    - dev
```

The Pipeline Failed Error

[image]

[image]

What could causes such an issue and how could we fix it, if possible.

Comment: `MYSQL_USER: root` must not be `root` any longer, e.g. use `MYSQL_USER: toor` (reason is given in the mysql service logs). And if you need a database, it's not a unit test. Just call it integration testing ^^

Comment: Check if the DB_HOST variable is correctly set in the test-unit job: You can add the command echo $DB_HOST to the before_script section of the test-unit job to check if the variable is set to 'mysql'.

Comment: yes it was just like @hakre said I used a user other than the root and it did work